# Is there a way to fix the initial Go/Golang FreeTDS+ODBC call being slow?

Tags: go, odbc, freetds

I'm using the ODBC driver with FreeTDS by Brainman (http://code.google.com/p/odbc), and I'm noticing that my initial DB stored procedure call is slow, and the other ones are as fast.

Here are the results of a test:

```
=== RUN TestLoadElitePartner
ELAPSED TrafficCheck:  456.0261ms
ELAPSED LoadEliteInfo:  123.0071ms
ELAPSED LiveFeed:  128.0073ms
--- PASS: TestLoadElitePartner (0.71 seconds)
PASS
```

The first call is 456ms, and the subsequent calls are more realistic, at ~125ish each, but still a bit slow. If I SWAP the order that these three db queries are called, the first one is always slow (~450ms) and the subsequent ones faster (~125ms), assumedly due to connection pooling.

Is there a way to FIX the initial call being THAT slow? 450ms does not seem reasonable to me.

My DB connection string is directly to an IP address, so this is not a DNS issue. I've read on http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/seemtooslow.htm that DNS and logging are the main issues that FreeTDS can be slow, but I do not have logging enabled and I am going directly off IP. Is there anything else I can do to optimize my ODBC/FreeTDS?

Comment: Just a guess, but have a look at or around line 56 of https://code.google.com/p/odbc/source/browse/driver.go . Try setting `drv.SetMaxIdleConns(0)` (http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxIdleConns) and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Are you sure this is not due to the server compiling the procedure (and possibly warming the caches when executing it subsequently) when it's being executed for the first time? You could use the standard SQL Server Profiler to see what happens "on the wire", with timings.